# community.to.membership in igraph 1.0

Tags: igraph

I have a quick question, is the function `community.to.membership` deprecated in igraph 1.0? I can find `membership` function, but it does not include the options `merges`, `steps`, and so on,

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `community.to.membership` is deprecated. However, you have `membership()` to retrieve the membership vector or `merges()` to retrieve the merge matrix. See `?communities` from the R prompt.

Comment: thanks @Tamás, then is not needed to specify the `steps` to get the membership right?

Comment: If you have a hierarchical clustering which has no membership yet, you can call `cut_at()` to cut the dendrogram after a given number of steps - this will give you the membership vector.